# Can I have users share images from my site on Instagram?

Tags: sharing, social-sharing-buttons, instagram

Is there a way for me to suggest that my users share the images from my website on Instagram? I've found share buttons for other sites like Facebook and Pinterest.

I ask because a user was uploading screenshots from the website to Instagram and getting a fair amount of interest in it. I would like to make that process easier for users.

Comment: See also on StackOverflow: [Instagram: Share photo from webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673156/instagram-share-photo-from-webpage)

Answer (score 16):

According to: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> - Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app. However, in the future we may give whitelist access to individual apps on a case by case basis.
> - We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

This means that if you do this you are probably going to be breaking the service agreement and you'll need to scrape and impersonate forms if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed pictures now. If you click on the ellipses on the websites, you get a choice to embed a picture, and you can copy and send the link. In the app, if you tap on the ellipses, it let's you "share."

Comment: Is there documentation? Can you show an example?

Comment: I can't post screenshots here, but try following the steps I outlined. I was trying to post something on my Tumblr, and it worked.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a place that shows an example, or paste in the code that you used on your tumblr?

Comment: http://blog.instagram.com/post/55095847329/introducing-instagram-web-embeds. Also: https://help.instagram.com/513918941996087

Comment: That appears to be embedding an image from Intragram into my website.   I'm looking for the other way around: sharing an image from my website to Instagram.